# Getting "AWT EVENTQueue-0" java .lang.nullpointerexception error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

i have no idea how im getting this error. ive made it so when i click on the time button, the timecombobox becomes visible. my code is below. Ive tryed different methods such as when the button is clicked i insert the timepanel with the combobox inserted inside it. Whats the reason why my code isnt working?

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class events extends JFrame {
// variables for JPanel
private JPanel timePanel;
private JButton timeButton;
 private JButton moneyButton;
private JButton hotelButton;
private JButton exitButton;


 public events() 
 {




setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

  JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
  buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
  add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
  JPanel timePanel = new JPanel();
  timePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
  timePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 240));

  add(timePanel,BorderLayout.EAST);   

   Time timeObject = new Time();
      timeObject.SelectTime();
      timePanel.add(timeObject.gettimePanel());
      timeObject.gettimePanel().setVisible(false);


  timeButton = new JButton("Time"); 
  buttonPanel.add(timeButton);

  moneyButton = new JButton("Price");
  buttonPanel.add(moneyButton);

  hotelButton = new JButton("Hotel");
  buttonPanel.add(hotelButton);

  exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
  buttonPanel.add(exitButton);


  buttontime clickTime = new buttontime();
  timeButton.addActionListener(clickTime);




   }

    //classes for Time
 public class buttontime implements ActionListener { //creating actionlistener for     clicking on timebutton to bring up a combobox
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickTime)  {
           Time timeObject = new Time();
      timeObject.SelectTime();
      timePanel.add(timeObject.gettimePanel());
      timeObject.gettimePanel().setVisible(true);


  }
  }






   public static void main (String args[]) {
events mainmenu = new events(); //object is created


mainmenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
mainmenu.setSize(600,400);
mainmenu.setVisible(true);
mainmenu.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
mainmenu.setTitle("Travel Agent System");
mainmenu.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

}





     import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

   import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 class Time
{

  private JComboBox timeairportbox;//comboboxes declared
  private String[] Airport = {"","East Midlands", "Birmingham", "Manchester",  "Heathrow"};//array of airports declared


public void SelectTime() {



  //combobox objects created
  timeairportbox = new JComboBox(Airport);//array is inserted into the JComboBox
  timeairportbox.setVisible(false);   // Combobox is placed in the timePanel




 }

 public JComponent gettimePanel() {
    return timeairportbox;
    }

    }




}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your application?

Comment: Did anyone ever explain to you that it your code is easier to read and understand if you follow the Java style conventions?  This code is horrible ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *shadowing* the variable `timePanel` in the constructor of `events`, so the class member variable never gets assigned, causing the `NPE`. replace

```
JPanel timePanel = new JPanel();
```

with

```
timePanel = new JPanel();
```

*Aside:* [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) show that class names start with an *uppercase* letter, which would make `events` `Events`.

Comment: You're welcome, in future, can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and format the code :)